# Error using predict function terra package in R

Tags: r, predict, terra

I get an error when trying to perform a spatial prediction using a previously fitted GLM model and a SpatRaster containing the environmental predictors. Does anyone know what could be causing this error?

this is my code:

```
env <- rast("data/rasters/predictors.tif")
cv_data <- SDM_list_new[[2477804]]$simple_glm
pr_cur_prob <- terra::predict(env, cv_data, cores = 1, type = "response")
#Error in .runModel(model, fun, d, nl, const, na.rm, index, ...) :
#    argument "cores" is missing, with no default
```

I have updated the terra package and also tried running the code with changing the number of the "cores" argument or omitting the cores argument, which did not help.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to answer your question as you do not include a minimal self-contained reproducible example. We also do not know what other packages you are using, and what their versions are. I am guessing that this happens because of some interference from another package. So I would suggest trying this without loading packages that are not strictly needed (and then perhaps adding them again to see where things go wrong).

The below (from `?terra::predict`) works fine for me.

```
library(terra)
#terra 1.7.29
logo <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))   
names(logo) <- c("red", "green", "blue")
p <- matrix(c(48, 48, 48, 53, 50, 46, 54, 70, 84, 85, 74, 84, 95, 85, 
   66, 42, 26, 4, 19, 17, 7, 14, 26, 29, 39, 45, 51, 56, 46, 38, 31, 
   22, 34, 60, 70, 73, 63, 46, 43, 28), ncol=2)

a <- matrix(c(22, 33, 64, 85, 92, 94, 59, 27, 30, 64, 60, 33, 31, 9,
   99, 67, 15, 5, 4, 30, 8, 37, 42, 27, 19, 69, 60, 73, 3, 5, 21,
   37, 52, 70, 74, 9, 13, 4, 17, 47), ncol=2)
xy <- rbind(cbind(1, p), cbind(0, a))
e <- extract(logo, xy[,2:3])
v <- data.frame(cbind(pa=xy[,1], e))
model <- glm(formula=pa~., data=v)

r0 <- predict(logo, model)
r1 <- predict(logo, model, cores=1)
r2 <- predict(logo, model, cores=2)
```

Comment: logo does not seem to be a raster stack. I hope terra have the same function as raster to perform predictions using raster stack.